# Generate cron value remaining identical based on a string

Tags: random, cron, ansible

As I'm using ansible to set cron tasks and as I want to avoid having the same tasks running exactly at the same time  on all my server, I'm looking for an elegant solution to generate cron "randomly" by keeping the indempotency when I re-run my ansible role.

I've made this working script :

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
    echo "Syntax error : at least one argument is needed"
    echo "Syntax: $0 string [ -hmbf ]"
    echo "-h : display only the hour"
    echo "-m : display only the minute"
    echo "-b : display both hour and minute"
    echo "-f : display both hour and minute in cron format"
    exit
fi

case $2 in
    -h|--hour)
    onlyhour=true
    ;;
    -m|--minute)
    onlyminute=true
    ;;
    -b|--both)
    bothhourminute=true
    ;;
    -f|--full)
    fullcron=true
    ;;
    *)
            # unknown option
    ;;
esac

n=$(md5sum <<< "$1")
number=$((0x${n%% *}))
number=${number#-}

position=0
while [  $position -lt ${#number} ]; do
        onenumber=${number:$position:1}
        twonumber=${number:$position:2}
        if [[ $onenumber -ge 0 && $onenumber -le 6 && -z ${hour+x} ]]; then hour=$onenumber; fi
        if [[ $twonumber -ge 0 && $twonumber -le 59 && -z ${minute+x} ]]; then minute=$twonumber; fi
        let position=position+1
        if [[ -n "$hour" && -n "$minute" ]]
                then
                        if [ "$onlyhour" = true ] ; then
                                echo $hour
                                exit 0
                        elif [ "$onlyminute" = true ] ; then
                                echo $minute
                                exit 0
                        elif [ "$fullcron" = true ] ; then
                                echo $minute $hour '* * *'
                                exit 0
                        else
                                echo $minute $hour
                                exit 0
                        fi
        fi
done
```

The idea is to call the script and give the server name as argument.

I'm nevertheless not convinced by my own solution. Is there a better way to do it? I'm looking for something directly available in Ansible.

Answer (score 4):

As of Ansible version 2.3, it’s also possible to initialize the random number generator from a seed. This way, you can create random-but-idempotent numbers:

{{ 59 |random(seed=inventory_hostname) }} * * * * root /script/from/cron

Comment: Now that Ansible 2.3 is out, this should really be the recommended way.  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

Idempotent `cron` task, with times seeded by `inventory_hostname`:

```
- cron:
    name: myjob
    job: myscript.sh
    minute: "{{ ( inventory_hostname | hash | list | map('int',0,16) | sum ) % 60 }}"
    hour: "{{ ( inventory_hostname | hash | list | map('int',0,16) | sum ) % 24 }}"
```

Comment: I really like this option - the 'randomness' is deterministic so Ansible won't keep changing the file.

Comment: And if you need to map onto a shorter range of hours (i.e. "2AM to 5AM"), replace the "% 24" with "% 3" then add 2 to the result.

Answer (score -1):

Use ansible `cron` module with random values

```
- cron: name='JOB_NAME' job="JOB" minute={{ 59 |random }} hour={{ 4 |random(start=3) }}
```

This will create cron job it's minute is in range (0-59) and hours in range (3-4)

Comment: This is interresting ... but not indempotent. The result will be different each time